# An issue with loader.c program

Tags: c, math, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Some time ago I started analysing loader.c - a program written by Ralph Loader as a contestant for Bignum Bakeoff competition (you can see my progress so far [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:LittlePeng9/Analysis_of_Loader%27s_program). However, as you can see there, I have found a problem which I don't know how to deal with. The question is - what value does xx take in the line `xx = Left (lastRight),`? It clearly takes the value from the answer Derive(xx) gives - it's actually the value of xx in that subroutine. But what value does it take in that subroutine? Well, we have to look at a sub-subroutine which appears there, and so on. This isn't infinite loop, because before calling Derive(xx) the argument is actually halved within MAYBE macro. But here is the problem - within the program, this number is at no point increased; it's halved multiple times. From how I understand this, all of these halvings impact the final value of xx we get is 0.

To sum up, it seems like, due to repeated recursive calls, xx is going to become 0, however it makes no sense, when looking at the program. So my question is:

> Does xx really always take value 0? If not, at what point is my reasoning incorrect?

You can find all the parts of Loader's program [here](http://homepages.ihug.co.nz/~suckfish/busy/busy.tar.gz), along with his explanation on how it works.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: mods: it is exactly clear what op is asking for. see his explicit blog entry http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:LittlePeng9/Analysis_of_Loader%27s_program about the analysis, and the description in the sources.

xx is monotonically descending, either by Derive(xx-1) or by MAYBE. This is even commented in the source code.

Since xx descending to 0 is the only while loop exit, and the loop is always ending, the answer is YES.

Comment: I think `xx` does not always take value 0. Notice that the `while` loop in `Derive` can terminate early because the `MAYBE` macro is used for the iteration condition. In that case `xx` will have some bits remaining.